# Component Test fail: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null on injected service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am running a should create test on a component that I expect to pass but it is failing with:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
```

I have a component (keywords-settings) that consumes a service (ProfileProvider), which in turn consumes a different service (AuthService).

ProfileProvider has a member id which is initialized by authService fetching a value:

```
export class ProfileProvider {
  private uri: string;
  public id: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private config: Configuration,
    private authService: Authentication) {
    this.uri = this.config.getConfigOption('apiUri');
    this.id = this.authService.getResult().user.id;
  }
```

Jasmine test is unable to read .user.id which is causing the error.

The constructor function is called on class initialization, whereas ngOnit is called after the constructor, after the component is created.

If I move...

```
 this.id = this.authService.getResult().user.id;
```

from the constructor and into ngOnit(){} the test passes, however this.id then evaluates to undefined.

I have tried stubbing the value of id:

```
 profileProvider = debugElement.injector.get(ProfileProvider);
    profileProvider.businessId = '2';
```

Which does not work.

If I hardcode the value in ProfileProvider, the test passes without issue.

---

Implemented Uğur Dinç's suggestion:

```
fdescribe('KeywordsSettingsComponent', () => {
  let component: KeywordsSettingsComponent,
  fixture: ComponentFixture<KeywordsSettingsComponent>,
  authService: Authentication,
  addKeywordsSpy: any,
  businessIdSpy: any;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ KeywordsSettingsComponent ],
      providers: [Configuration, HttpClient, Authentication]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    authService = TestBed.get(Authentication);
    businessIdSpy = spyOn(authService , "getResult").and.returnValue(of({
      user: {
        id: '2'
      }
    }));

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(KeywordsSettingsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.ngOnInit();

  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


});
```

Error has changed to: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz/plunker?

Answer (score 0):

You should mock the getResult in your authService like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({            
    ... // configuration
    })

    authService = TestBed.get(Authentication);
    getResultSpy = spyOn(authService , "getResult").and.returnValue(of({
      user: {
        id: '2'
      }
    }));

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(InviteComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

and don't forget to import `of`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/of';
```

Comment: I have implemented what you have suggested, there is a new error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined```

Comment: @Sandbagger Just to confirm, are you testing your HTML as well?